# Not sure how to write a test case for conditionally rendered ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My app initially renders with a loading placeholder within the component, after 5 seconds different elements are rendered.  I want to test this component with jest and enzyme.

My issue is that when I test it and console.log(wrapper.debug()) it only shows the loading part.

Now my question is how I can unit test the conditional part.

My App.js

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false)
    }, 5000);
  },[])
  if(loading){
    return <span>loading....</span>
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My App.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

describe("app component", () => {
  it("loading state", () => {
    const setState = jest.fn();
    const useStateMock = (initState) => [initState, setState];
    jest.spyOn(React, "useState").mockImplementation(useStateMock);
    jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect").mockImplementation(setState);
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    const result = wrapper.find("#abc");
    result.simulate("click");
    wrapper.update();
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Honestly, I would not place the timer in your component like that to show a loading text.  Instead you would typically have a global mechanism to check if a page or api call has been completed and store that flag in a datastore.  If you absolutely had to do it your way, (which is not ideal) then I would extract the <div className="App"> as a separate component and test that by itself.

Comment: You don't quite have the correct component code to mock the react hook, but your `useState` mock also doesn't update the value it returns to the component under test so the separate conditions can be exercised. Have you considered react-testing-library? It is a little easier (IMHO) for testing UI than enzyme.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use: `jest.setTimeout(6000)`

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

describe("app component", () => {
  it("loading state", () => {
    const setState = jest.fn();
    const useStateMock = (initState) => [initState, setState];
    jest.spyOn(React, "useState").mockImplementation(useStateMock);
    jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect").mockImplementation(setState);
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    const result = wrapper.find("#abc");
    result.simulate("click");
    wrapper.update();
    jest.setTimeout(6000)
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
  })
```